# why task.run does not print the output in order of execution in c#

Tags: c#, task

```
       Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";
        // Define and run the task.
        Task taskA = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));
        // Output a message from the calling thread.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread '{0}'.",
                            Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        taskA.Wait();
```

why "hello from taskA" is printed after "Hello from thread Main"

Comment: You'll have to learn about [threading race bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and what to do about them, this is the most basic one there is.

Comment: Wellcome to multithreading world :)

Comment: Isn't it the whole point of that exercise to show it's **not** in order? If it were in order, what's the point of a thread or task?

Answer (score 1):

Task.Run creates a new tread to execute the code you have passed from it. It is scheduled to do that work by the TaskScheduler and most probably some Thread Management stuff deep down in .NET and the OS. 
Which code actually executes first is probably non-deterministic (ie. It can't be guaranteed) and it what is known as a 'Race Condition'. However in practice the overhead of starting the new thread and executing your code will almost certainly always take longer than the original thread takes to execute the next line. So in **this** 'instance' it will probably always execute second.